# Remover item do ListView

Tags: android, listview

Bom eu estou com uma lista, no qual tem alguns itens que o próprio usuário cria. Com isso eu estou querendo também dar uma opção ao usuário de remover os itens para não ficar acumulado, assim pesquisei e achei uma maneira utilizando o `onItemLongClickListener` de remover o item. Segue o código:

```
  adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Bom até aí tudo bem quando eu dei o `LongClick` ele removeu o item, porém depois que fui em outra `activity` do app e voltei para essa `activity` do `ListView` o item que eu removi apareceu novamente, o que eu faço para consertar isso, para ir à outra `activity` voltar e o item continuar removido ?

Observação, estou utilizando SQLiteDatabase.

Obrigado!

Comment: Imagino que você esta construindo seu adapter com um ArrayList/List, certo? Você está removendo esse item dessa lista também?

Comment: Eu criei o meu ArrayAdapter, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta mais só estou utilizando esses codigo aí em cima para remover o item, fora isso eu consigo remover o item, mais ele não salva .. @siachester

Comment: hum...Então é o seguinte...Verificou se no sqliter está removendo o valor? Ele pode está persistindo na inserção por conta do valor que não saiu da coluna.

Comment: porque eu não consigo ver os itens que o usuario criou @Rafael

Comment: Pode sim. Se você simular um usuário. Realizando todas as etapas e revendo seu código no onItemLongClickListener, verificar se há alguma linha de código que remove, também, no sqliter.

Comment: tem essa opção não...

Comment: O problema é que, no ciclo de vida de uma Activity e dependendo do seu código, seu adapter é refeito depois que você volta para a tela. Se você não persistir a exclusão do item no seu banco de dados interno, não ira adiantar apenas excluir do seu adapter

Answer (score 2):

Você realizou a primeira etapa, que foi apagar o item do ListView. No entanto, este item irá persistir, uma vez que não foi apagado do Banco de dados. Quando a Atividade é recriada, a lista é reorganizada, pois a consulta daquele item "deletado", encontra o item no Banco.

Recomendo a você rever seus código e inserir algo como isto, para realizar a última etapa que falta para resolver o seu problema:

```
 //---delete um valor em particular ---
public boolean deleteValor(String nome) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + nome, null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Sim, porém o que eu coloco em KEY_NAME ?

Comment: static final String KEY_NAME = "minhaColuna"; 
//  CASO ESTEJA FORA DO ESCOPO  ------------------

       Ou String KEY_NAME = "minhaColuna"; // CASO ESTEJA DENTRO DO ESCOPO

"db" é o seu banco

Comment: e como eu vou utilizar ele no longclick ?

Comment: 1 - Você não apresentou o seu código por completo.
2 - Isto é uma função booleana com retorno, então é simples entender.
3 - Você precisa estudar mais sobre como colocar isso em sua lógica. Eu não vejo sua lógica por completa.

Comment: Não posso postar meu codigo...

Comment: Sinto muito, amigo. Não é que eu não queira, é que não sei por onde começar, já que você não faz a sua parte. No entanto, caso um dia você entenda e resolva, volte aqui vote positivo pra mim  :)

Comment: é porque não consigo ver logica a parte do seu codigo encaixada no meu codigo..

Comment: eu sei que um dia vou conseguir então já te dei um positivo ai valeu mesmo assim!

Comment: Dou-lhe uma dica! Estude mais sobre: funções booleanas com retorno em Java.

Comment: Beleza vou estudar sim!

Comment: :) SHOW!!!!!!!!